# How can I use fractions with hotkeys for translation/rotation/scale?

Tags: transforms, shortcut

For instance if I want to rotate an object by 360/16 degrees around the z-axis, I would expect to type: R Z 360/16. However the / key acts as a kind of toggle and midway through typing pressing <kbd>/</kbd> turns 360 into 1/360, so I end up with a rotation of 1/36016 degrees as the rotation if I were to keep typing.

How do I disable this and allow it to evaluate fractions or other python expressions similar to other transform property boxes?

Comment: Finally .......

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You simply need to use the <kbd>=</kbd> operator to enter [Advanced Entry Mode](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/precision/numeric_input.html), after that you can enter your fractional value or simple Python expression:

[image]